# Running into character issues while trying to migrate a PostgreSQL database to a MySQL database using MySQL Workbench

Tags: mysql, postgresql, mysql-workbench, mysql-error-1064, utf8mb4

The PostgreSQL instance I'm using as my source database is using UTF-8 encoding and a cp1252 charset/collation. I'm trying to use a utf8mb4/utfmb4_unicode_520_ci charset/collation on my target database. I set all relevant server/client charset arguments to utf8mb4/utfmb4_unicode_520_ci to ensure that the data is read properly. Despite this, I still get a massive wealth of errors like these:

```
    04:04:25 [INF][      copytable]: Statement execution failed: Incorrect string value: '\x92Angel...' for column 'user' at row 1:
    ...
    04:04:21 [INF][      copytable]: Statement execution failed: Incorrect string value: '\xE1cs' for column 'lname' at row 1:
    ...
    04:04:17 [INF][      copytable]: Statement execution failed: Incorrect string value: '\x85' for column 'user' at row 1:
    ...etc
```

The string I'm using for the configuration of the target's charset/collation is this:

```
    preInit=SET default_storage_engine=InnoDB,character_set_connection=utf8mb4,collation_connection=utf8mb4_unicode_520_ci,collation_server=utf8mb4_unicode_520_ci,character_set_server=utf8mb4
```

How can I get rid of these errors, or at the very least, ignore them so that they don't halt the copy of the entire rest of the table? At this point I don't even care if the data is 100% accurate, I just want it to WORK.

I've tried everything I've read on here and it's been no dice. Any help whatsoever is greatly appreciated.

Comment: What is utf8mb4 supposed to be? And InnoDB is a MySQL thing. Are you sure you haven't got your database systems mixed up?

Comment: MySQL’s “utf8” charset isn’t actually unicode as it only supports up to 3-byte characters. Utf8mb4 is their solution to this. InnoDB (in the target db string) is referring to the MySQL database that the data from the PostgreSQL database is being migrated to. I’m quite sure I haven’t got anything switched up, as the migration has worked for some tables (albeit, only because they apparently didn’t contain any messed up characters).

Comment: Ah, I see, that's the mysql end of things. Apologies - I'd misread your question and thought your were asking about the PostgreSQL. However, those codes shown in the error don't look like valid UTF8 to me. Make sure you are dumping the data in utf8 not cp1252 and if you are sure, narrow it down to a single bad row so you can dump the character codes in use + get a proper diagnosis

Comment: That's exactly what I was thinking - it's not valid UTF8 at all. In the first error (Incorrect string value: '\x92Angel...'), the full username is "D’Angelo". \x92 is is a "RIGHT SINGLE QUOTATION MARK" in Unicode. If it were properly reading as utf8mb4 then there (theoretically) should be no error. It also seems that for some reason, MySQL workbench is trying to count the characters after the Unicode character as extra bytes (perhaps because it can't read \x92 alone?).

Comment: @xn - `\x92` is not a valid utf8 encoding; it could be a quote in cp1252.

Comment: @RichardHuxton - MySQL's `utf8mb4` is the same encoding as the outside world's `UTF-8`.

Answer (score 0):

Those codes look like cp1252, not utf8.  If that is typical of the postgres data, then you should state that cp1252 is the encoding (aka charset) of the source.